# How to handle multi criterias search in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch, laravel-5, get

I have a little problem with doing a filter on my website.
I have a form which is present in all pages, with this form user can search for products by name and category. The code looks like this:

```
<form method = "GET" action = "{!! route('search_product') !!}">
   <input type = "text" name = "searchText"/>
   <select name="category">
    ...
   </select>
</form>
```

When user submits form I'll get an url like this: search_result.php?searchText=test&category=1

It's work fine. The problem is that on the search_result page I have another form which purpose is to enable user to narrow product list by price.

```
<form method = "GET" action="{!! route('search_product') !!}">
    <input name = "min" type = "text"/>
    <input name = "max" type ="text" />
</form>
```

By doing this The precedents parameters(searchText and category) are removed when submitting form. So how to keep them.

PS: Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 hidden inputs, filled with the values of *searchText* and *category*, in the new form and this way you will have the values after the second submit.

```
<form method = "GET" action="{!! route('search_product') !!}">
    <input name="searchText" type="hidden" value="<?=$searchtext;?>" />
    <input name="category" type="hidden" value="<?=$category;?>" />
    <input name = "min" type = "text"/>
    <input name = "max" type ="text" />
</form>
```

Comment: I figured it out myself, however thanks for your answer.